# How to change the symbolic link in development env shared hosting laravel?

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I have a Larevel-app in a shared hosting. For the setup, I had to create a new folder in the main carpet of the hosting and copy the content of my public folder to public_html. I made changes in index.php and all working fine and nice. However, when a user upload a file that needs to be public, this file it saved in the myproject/storage/app/public path but not reflected in the public_html/storage so I can't access to it.

Reading the documentation, I know it is a problem with the symbolic link.

how can I change it?

Note: I can't access to the cdm because it is a shared hosting without access. It is window hosting.

Comment: You can delete old Symbolic link, and create new one by `ln -s folder_path symbolink_name`

Comment: you stand in storage/app/ folder, delete storage/app/public folder , then `ln -s ../../public_html public`

Comment: `ln -s ../../public_html/storage public`

Answer (score 0):

make this route in web.php then hit this

```php
Route::get('/artisan/storage', function() {
    $command = 'storage:link';
    $result = Artisan::call($command);
    return Artisan::output();
})
```

Comment: Great idea! However, didn't work. I think because the public folder is outside the project folder.